# Passing params in Redux + React Native + react-navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to pass a param from MenuScreen.js to the ProfileScreen.js. I am new to React Native and Redux. Using react-navigation for navigation, I am able to push to  new screen with a button.

Using

> Button onPress={() => dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile', params: { user: 'baz' } }))}
>       title="Profile" />

I am able to pass the params but I don't know how access it on the profile screen.

Using

> this.props.navigation.state.params

in *ProfileScreen.js* is giving an error that

> this.props.navigation

is undefined.

Below is the code,

**MainScreen.js**

```
const MainScreen = ({ dispatch }) => {

return (
<View>

  <Button
    onPress={() =>
      dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile', params: { user: 'baz' } }))}
    title="Profile"
  />
</View>
);
};

MainScreen.propTypes = {
dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

MainScreen.navigationOptions = {
title: 'Main',
}; 

const mapStateToProps = state => ({

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainScreen);
```

**ProfileScreen.js**

```
const params  = this.props.navigation.state.params;

const ProfileScreen = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.welcome}>
   {params}
  </Text>
  </View>
);

ProfileScreen.navigationOptions = {
 title: 'Profile',
};

export default ProfileScreen;
```

**index.reducer.js**

```
import { AppNavigator } from '../navigators/AppNavigator';

const initialNavState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
  AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Main')
);

function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
  let nextState;
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
      break;
  }
  return nextState || state;
}

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  nav,
});

export default AppReducer;
```

**AppNavigator.js**

```
import MainScreen from '../components/MainScreen';
import MainScreen from '../components/MainScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../components/ProfileScreen';

export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
 Main: { screen: MainScreen },
 Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});

const AppWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
  <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({ dispatch, state: 
  nav })} /> 
);

AppWithNavigationState.propTypes = {
   dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
   nav: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 nav: state.nav,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppWithNavigationState);
```

**index.ios.js**

```
class NavChecks extends React.Component {
store = createStore(AppReducer);

render() {
  return (
    <Provider store={this.store}>
      <AppWithNavigationState />
    </Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NavChecks', () => NavChecks);

export default NavChecks;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try passing props to `ProfileScreen`:

```
const ProfileScreen = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.welcome}>
   {props.navigation.state.params.user}
  </Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: You nailed it! It worked! Thanks mradziwon! I've just started with React-Native, with your permission, can you provide me a way to contact you so that I can ask some questions for help when I get stuck again? Thanks again sir!

Answer (score 0):

try passing props to ProfileScreen. In my point of view use react-native-router-flux for navigation which is more flexible i think in which you can pass parameters as props while navigating to the other page

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using withNavigation in react-navigation.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withNavigation(MyComponent));
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html